# Files ".uuid" remain after package removal

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I recognised that after purging some packages (e. g. `texlive-lang-japanese`), directories remain because they contain a file named `.uuid` (e. g. `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipaexfont-gothic/.uuid`). It contains only a single UUID which seems to vary for every `.uuid` file, but I couldn't find that UUID anywhere.

What's the purpose of these files? How to find out wether they can be removed without any problems later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: [Debian bug #897040 fontconfig: .uuid files in font directories not removed during purge](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897040)

The files are internal fontconfig cache files and should be removed when removing the font packages. You can remove the files manually, there should be no problem with that.

Comment: Maybe you might know how to check whether I a) definitely can remove the files manually or b) better should leave them where (and how) they are…? Actually, what are they good for? Why do they exist at all??? (Maybe that goes beyond the scope of the question, doesn't it?)

Comment: As I said, these are fontconfig cache file, they are (or actually were used, if I understand it correctly, these are no longer used in newer fontconfig) used to check whether to font is cached or not. More in this bugreport: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101889 You can remove the files for uninstalled fonts.